# setting an array element with a sequence after one-hot-encoding with scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have been using scikit-learn's linear svc model for a binary classification problem.

Example row from the dataset:

```
    PassengerId Survived    Pclass  Name                    Sex    Age  SibSp   Parch   Ticket      Fare    Cabin   Embarked
0   1           0           3       Braund, Mr. Owen Harris male    22.0    1   0       A/5 21171   7.25    NaN     S
```

I transformed the data into numbers using the OneHotEncoder and the ColumnTransformer from scikit-learn:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

categorical_features = ["Name", "Sex", "Ticket", "Cabin", "Embarked"]
encoder = OneHotEncoder()
transformer = ColumnTransformer([("one_hot",
                                   encoder,
                                   categorical_features)],
                                   remainder="passthrough")

transformed_X = transformer.fit_transform(X)
transformed_X
```

It returned me a scipy.sparse._csr.csr_matrix, so I changed it into a dataframe using:

```
transformed_X = pd.DataFrame(transformed_X)
```

Then I resplit the data and fit it to the model

```
transformed_X_train, transformed_X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(transformed_X,
                                                                            y,
                                                                            test_size=0.2)

from sklearn import svm
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(transformed_X_train, y_train)
```

Unfortunately, I got an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a real number, not 'csr_matrix'

...

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I tried searching online, but I can't didn't find a good solution to my problem.
Can someone please help, because I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Always provide the full error traceback. Also here we need the code for the dataframe-from-sparse and model fitting, and preferably a sample dataset. And probably a bit of the introductory code isn't actually needed.

Comment: @BenReiniger Thanks I added the suggested items :)

Comment: That's not the full error traceback, and it doesn't indicate where in your code the error gets thrown.  I don't think you can turn a sparse array into a dataframe by just calling `pd.DataFrame(the_array)`; try https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix.html

Comment: If you use `transformed_X = pd.DataFrame(transformed_X.toarray())`, does that prevent the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it! I first filled in the missing data that was in the dataframe before encoding it, then when I one-hot-encoded it I did it with the entire training set, not only the X, like so:

```
transformed_X = transformer.fit_transform(train)
transformed_X
```

The difference between the X and the full training set is that X was the training set without the target values (In this case, it was whether they survived or not).

Thanks! :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).